# vmware esx vlan without physical switch?

Tags: vmware-esx, vlan, vmware-vsphere

Based on what I know if you're using a vlan in a VMWare ESX vswitch connected to a physical port you should connect that port to a trunk port on a physical switch. Is this right?

Can you give me a solution to using vlan in VMWare switches without using physical ports?

Comment: Tweaked the English in your question to clarify what I think you're asking -- If I got it wrong please let me know & I'll revert.

Answer (score 3):

You might use a vSwitch that has no physical ports associated with it when you want to create a network between VMs that isn't attached to any physical network. A practical application of such a vSwitch, for example, might be facilitating communication between VMs that provide some kind of "back-end" functionality (database servers, let's say) for "front end" VMs (like, say, web servers) running on the same host machine. Perhaps that network between the "front end" and "back end" servers has no need to be exposed to any physical machines (or, maybe, for perceived or real security reasons you'd explicitly prefer not to expose it to physical machines) and, as such, you create a vSwitch that has only the virtual NICs from the "front end" and "back end" VMs attached but no physical NICs.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule of thumb is that the physical port you connect to has to be configured the same way as the port on the vswitch you are connecting to it.

So if the vswitch port has an untagged VLAN and three tagged VLANs, then the physical switch port needs to be configured the same way.

The implementation details can vary from switch to switch.

Answer (score 0):

i think found my answer, to use vlanning and other switching capabilities should install cisco nexus v1000 and use that for vlanning. only problem to test is my low speed internet connection (256 kbps "in iran its a normal speed :)") and cannot download now, i will test and say result soon. but i think its 90% ok.

http://www.ciscosystemsverified.biz/en/US/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus1000/sw/4_0/install/software/guide/install_n1000v.pdf